# java RMI newbie-- some basic questions about SSL and auth/.rate limiting an RMI service

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to work to secure a java based RMI service using SSL.

I have some basic questions about the capabilities of using SSL.  Specifically, from what I understand, the client and server connecting via SSL will need to have appropriate credential certificates in both client and server, for a client to be granted access to the server. Am I correct in my understanding?

Also, what I want to know is, can a person who is already using my RMI service and has access to a client machine , make a copy of the certificate in the client machine to other client machines-- and then invoke my RMI service from those other machines as well?

How do I  prevent such a situation from occurring? I mean, in a REST API you can use OAuth authentication, can we have some kind of authentication in an RMI Service?

Also, can I  possibly limit usage of the RMI service? For eg, a specific client may be allowed to make only 5000 calls per day to my RMI service, and if he makes more calls the calls occurring after the 5000 calls limit are all denied? How do I do such rate limiting and/or authentication for my RMI Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, from what I understand, the client and server connecting via SSL will need to have appropriate credential certificates in both client and server, for a client to be granted access to the server. Am I correct in my understanding?

No. Only the server needs a certificate. The client certificate is optional.

> Also, what I want to know is, can a person who is already using my RMI service and has access to a client machine , make a copy of the certificate in the client machine to other client machines-- and then invoke my RMI service from those other machines as well?

Certainly. Physical security of the certificates and the application is your problem. SSL can't solve it for you.

> Also, can I possibly limit usage of the RMI service? For eg, a specific client may be allowed to make only 5000 calls per day to my RMI service, and if he makes more calls the calls occurring after the 5000 calls limit are all denied? How do I do such rate limiting and/or authentication for my RMI Service?

Code it yourself. Stick a daily counter in the database.